# C++ error -- expression must have integral or enum type -- getting this from a string with concatenation?

Tags: c++

C++ error **expression must have integral or enum type** getting this from a string with concatenation?

So in the `toString()` of a class in C++ I have the code:

```
string bags = "Check in " + getBags() + " bags";
```

I thought I could declare a string like this? (I'm coming from a Java background and trying to learn C++). The `bags` is underlined in Visual Studio though and the problem is:

> expression must have integral or enum type.

`getBags()` just returns an `int`.

Another example where this happens is with:

```
string totalPrice = "Grand Total: " + getTotalPrice();
```

`getTotalPrice()` returns a `float` and is what is underlined with the error.

But then if I put in a line like:

```
string blah = getBags() + "blah";
```

No errors.

What am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`"Check in "` is actually a `const char *`.
Adding `getBags()` (an `int`) to it yields another `const char*`. The compiler error is generated because you cannot add two pointers.

You need to convert both `"Check in "` and `getBags()` to strings before concatenating them:

```
string bags = std::string("Check in ") + std::to_string(getBags()) + " bags";
```

`" bags"` will be implicitly converted to a `string`.

Comment: You can use std::to_string only if you use c++11

Comment: Anyone know which Visual Studio version supports C++11?

Comment: vs11 or vs12. I'm not sure.

Comment: To date, Visual C++ support for C++11 is incomplete. It has, however, supported `std::to_string()` since VS2010.

Comment: is it necessary to have std::string() around "Check in "? Won't this also be implicitly converted to a string?

Comment: @aquirdturtle - Yes, `"Check in "` will be implicitly converted to an `std::string`, so the explicit conversion is not necessary.

Answer (score 7):

when using + to append strings the first element must have operator+, const char* doesn't have it.

therefore you should to make a string from it:

```
string bags = string("Check in ") + getBags() + " bags";
```

or to do it in to steps:

```
string bags = string("Check in ") + getBags() + " bags";
```

**EDIT:**
More problem is the int returned from the method, for some reason, string doesn't have operator+ for int.

So you better use stringstream like this:

```
#include <sstream>
....
ostringstream s;
s<<"Check in " << getBags() << " bags";
string bags = s.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `std::to_string(getBags())`. You can only concatenate strings with strings.

Comment: In this case, do I have to specifically set up a toString function for getBages or does to_string() by default just return whatever getBags() returns (in string form)?  So, if int bags = 5 to_string(getBags()) would print out as 5? Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to create your own function as std::to_string() is a part of the <string> library. [Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: You can use std::to_string only if you use c++11

Comment: @SHR I suppose a more general solution is better, but he said he's using Visual Studio- which has had support for C++11 since 2010.